# Problem with Vietnamese keyboard on non-Microsoft applications

Tags: apps, windows-10-mobile, insider-preview, keyboard

I am using a Lumia 640XL running Window 10, version 1607, OS build 10.0.14356.1000.

I've got a problem with the keyboard. I can only type within Microsoft apps (such as Messaging, Edge etc.) but I am not able to type anything on other non-Microsoft apps (such as Facebook, Messenger, 6tag etc.) even though the keyboard does appear when I touch the field. Nothing appears when I touch the letters, numbers on keyboard.

A soft reset didn't work. So how can I fix it?

**UPDATE:** It's is a problem with the Vietnamese keyboard. i.e. I can type English normally. I have updated the title to reflect the same.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your phone? Soft-reset?

Comment: Try removing and adding the keyboard again. @RareNCool He already mentioned in his question that a soft reset didn't help. However nothing was said about restarting the phone.

Comment: @KolappanNathan See the edit. That part was added in after my comment, rather than replying to the comment itself.

Comment: @RareNCool Sorry I didn't notice that.